# DLNA Server/Control Point like Windows Media Player

Tags: 12.04, upnp, dlna

Yes, I know that most questions ending with "like Windows" are odd, but this one really bothers me ;)

If you ever used some DLNA renderer (in my case DLNA-enabled loudspeakers) you probably know the handy "play to"-feature.

From my knowledge of DLNA stuff I would guess, that Windows Media Player is both a DLNA server and control point here, so my question is:

Is there any similar software for Linux accomplishing the same thing with minimal configuration effort? I normally use Banshee for my music library, but it doesn't seem that there is anything available for Banshee...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The control points in Gupnp-tools  are very basic, more a testing tool than a every day media player. Try rygel as a DLNA server and eezUPNP as a control point. There is also kinsky by Linn, but I wasn't able to get it to work, keeps crashing. Another alternative may be serviio, but I haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the gupnp-tools package. Among others it adds

- A uPnP AV Control Point and
- A uPnP Universal Control Point

After adding the package to your system type gupnp into your dash to find these programs.

Reference: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1491399

Answer (score 0):

For me my best option for now are Leia and Minimserver, both very stable.